# How to control white space between bars in seaborn bar plots?

Tags: python, bar-chart, seaborn

I have following simple example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['Alex',25],['Bob',34],['Sofia',26],["Claire",35]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])
df["sex"]=["male","male","female","female"]
```

I use following code to plot barplots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns

age_plot=sns.barplot(data=df,x="Name",y="Age", hue="sex",dodge=False)
age_plot.get_legend().remove()
plt.setp(age_plot.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
plt.ylim(0,40)
age_plot.tick_params(labelsize=14)
age_plot.set_ylabel("Age",fontsize=15)
age_plot.set_xlabel("",fontsize=1)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Produces following bar plot:

[image]

**My question: how can I control de whitespace between bars? I want some extra white space between the male (blue) and female (orange) bars.**

Output should look like this (poorly edited in `MS PPT`):

[image]

I have found several topics on this for `matplotplib` (e.g.https://python-graph-gallery.com/5-control-width-and-space-in-barplots/) but not for `seaborn`. I'd prefer to use `seaborn` because of the easy functionality to color by `hue`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possibility is to insert an empty bar in the middle:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Alex', 'Bob', 'Sofia', 'Claire'], 'Age': [15, 18, 16, 22], 'Gender': ['M', 'M', 'F', 'F']})
df = pd.concat([df[df.Gender == 'M'], pd.DataFrame({'Name': [''], 'Age': [0], 'Gender': ['M']}), df[df.Gender == 'F']])

age_plot = sns.barplot(data=df, x="Name", y="Age", hue="Gender", dodge=False)
age_plot.get_legend().remove()
plt.setp(age_plot.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
plt.ylim(0, 40)
age_plot.tick_params(labelsize=14)
age_plot.tick_params(length=0, axis='x')
age_plot.set_ylabel("Age", fontsize=15)
age_plot.set_xlabel("", fontsize=1)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Hi JohanC, I was busy at work so I couldn't reply yet. Although I guess there is probably a more pythonic way to do this, your solution works. Thanks!